# Parsing JSON HTTP object in RUBY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have written the following code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('somejsonfile')
puts uri

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
puts http
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
puts request
response = http.request(request)
puts response
```

when i print the above items i get the output:

```
#<Net::HTTP:0x26507b8>
#<Net::HTTP::Get:0x2650638>
#<Net::HTTPMovedPermanently:0x264f750>
#<Net::HTTP::Get:0x264e208>
```

somewhat like this.

how do i get the JSON objects in proper format.

Thanks.!

Comment: Maybe checking out what the methods you're using actually return would be useful.

Comment: return not helping either.!

Comment: ... I'm saying to look at the documentation for those methods so you know what you're actually *doing*.

Answer (score 1):

Your question lacks a lot of informatin. I *assume* you have some HTTP service at `'somejsonfile'` URL, which returns some json. If this is the case, and the URL is corret, the JSON should be in the response body.

Try parsing the `body` of the `response`:

```
my_json = JSON.parse(response.body)
```

Comment: this helps but if i want to do for a certain link.. and that too https

Comment: you want to do _what_ for a certain link? is the input a JSON or a URL?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `JSON.parse()` instead of `URI.parse`

Comment: It called for a (JSON::ParserError) Error

Comment: Okay.. What format are you trying to achieve?
Try your old method but change your `puts` lines to:
    puts http.to_s,
    puts request.to_s,
    puts response.to_s,

Comment: And i am trying to get the JSON object from the certain link and simply read it.